# How can I use MUI TextField with "select" and "multiple" props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create multiple select input but had problem with the TextField because it is not accepting multiple props My TextField is shown in the code block.

```
 <TextField
  label={crmFieldTitleMap(value, t)}
  size="small"
  variant="outlined"
  select
  multiple
  value={....}
  onChange={....}
  input={<OutlinedInput />}
  renderValue={....}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
    {value.options.length &&
      value.options.map((item) => (
        <MenuItem key={crmFieldTitleMap(item, t)} value={item.value}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={
              crmPostData[value.value]
                ? crmPostData[value.value].includes(item.value)
                : false
            }
          />
          <ListItemText primary={crmFieldTitleMap(item, t)} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
</TextField>;
```

**With TextField I can't select multiple items but label seems pretty nice**
[image: With TextField]

Then I found a solution to choose multiple select which I used   and  as shown in the code block.

```
<FormControl className="w-full ">
  <InputLabel id="multiple_select_thingy">{titleMultiple(value, t)}</InputLabel>

  <Select
    labelId="multiple_select_thingy"
    label={titleMultiple(value, t)}
    size="small"
    variant="outlined"
    multiple
    disabled={....}
    value={....}
    onChange={....}
    input={<OutlinedInput />}
    renderValue={....}
    MenuProps={MenuProps}
  >
    {value.options.length &&
      value.options.map((item) => (
        <MenuItem key={crmFieldTitleMap(item, t)} value={item.value}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={
              crmPostData[value.value]
                ? crmPostData[value.value].includes(item.value)
                : false
            }
          />
          <ListItemText primary={crmFieldTitleMap(item, t)} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>;
```

**With Select I can select multiple items perfectly but the label seems weird.**
[image: With Select]

**Also when there are no items selected input gets weird too**
[image: With Select no input]

Answer (score 1):

Check `SelectProps` prop at https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

`multiple` should be included within `SelectProps` in `TextField`